# Putting a CMS framework into an MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, blogs

I have an MVC application in process of development and want to see if I can create or integrate it into an MVC-based CMS environment. The idea is that the application will appear to run in an environment wherein the user can actually add/edit web pages, download documents do blogs, handle Facebook integration etc.

In some respects I am almost looking for an Application Framework but that is not entirely the case. The application uses EF with an IRepository to allow switchable back-ends (including switching out EF). The key requirement is simply within the same solution to be able to provide a CMS type of management.

Architecturally I have thought of a side-by-side approach and also using a Module type approach wherein the app sits inside a CMS system.

In the immediate term does anyone have any comments, advise or experience as to how I could do this?

Comment: Question edited to present original intent of to find a suitable architectural approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the ASP.NET MVC based [AtomSite](http://blogsvc.codeplex.com/). It may have the features you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like the answer finally came along with the [Orchard Project](http://www.orchardproject.net/) which looks crisp and (reasonably) light-weight and provides a good MVC basis with Application Framework features for application development.